# Batch file to upload .txt to FTP

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I have setup a separate FTP account for this.

Here is the info:

```
FTP Username: ahk@proflightsimulatoreview.com
FTP Server: ftp.proflightsimulatoreview.com
FTP Server Port: 21
FTP Password: ahktest
```

Text file I want to upload: `C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\ftptest\thetest.txt`

Please show me how to do this with batch. My understanding is that you make a separate txt file with the FTP commands and then you use a batch file to run it. Well I must have not plugged in the info right because it didn't work.

So here I am giving you the information. Please show me how to upload a text file.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I have honestly tried all that. I realize I am asking to be completely spoonfed, but I have seriously been trying for hours. I gave the FTP account info so that someone could help me fill all the blanks in, since I am obviously doing it wrong. Also, I do not want to upload from a command prompt, I just want to run the batch file and have it done for me

Comment: what happens when you run the script from that site?

Comment: didnt work the first time, but I'll try again. thanks again

Comment: Have you tried the [ncFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) from the command line?? Works like a charm for all my needs of transmitting files to FTP from a command prompt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just put HELLO.TXT in your ftp root by;

**1**. Saving this as `MYFTP.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo user ahk@proflightsimulatoreview.com> ftpcmd.dat
echo ahktest>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.proflightsimulatoreview.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

**2**. From the command line, in the same directory as `MYFTP.BAT`, running;

```
MYFTP.BAT c:\temp\hello.txt
```

result

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 05:17. Server port: 21.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
ftp> user ahk@proflightsimulatoreview.com
331 User ahk@proflightsimulatoreview.com OK. Password required

230-OK. Current restricted directory is /
230 0 Kbytes used (0%) - authorized: 51200 Kb
ftp> put hello.txt
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 59363
226-0 Kbytes used (0%) - authorized: 51200 Kb
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.563 seconds (measured here), 14.20 bytes per second
ftp: 8 bytes sent in 0.34Seconds 0.02Kbytes/sec.
ftp> quit
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 1 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer...it doesnt seem to be working correctly though. I opened up a command prompt, typed cd C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\ftptest\  to get into the right directory, and then typed FTP.bat C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\ftptest\thetest.txt
 Now it seems stuck...nothing else is happening :(

Comment: it is making the ftpcmd.dat file so I know that it is somewhat working. so frustrating:(

Comment: try temp disabling the windows firewall

Comment: its off...never had it on. I can use filezilla and clients to connect perfectly. what does your  ftpcmd.dat read while it is uploading?

Comment: Mine looks like this:  
user ahk@proflightsimulatoreview.com
ahktest
put -n
quit

Comment: sorry! when I tested it I used a junk qweqweqe.BAT file and used the tidier FTP.BAT name in the example - FTP.BAT/FTP.EXE - the names conflict; rename the .BAT file to MYFTP.BAT or similar and it should work

Comment: Now I get the error, 'ftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Perhaps this is my problem all along. Do I not have the necessary windows files for ftp? I am running windows 7.

Comment: THANK THANK THANK YOU SO MUCH :D I had to put the .bat files in the system32 folder for it to work. Otherwise it couldnt find the FTP command? Thanks man, you are the best!

Comment: Your welcome, if you make the 1st line in the bat file cd `c:\windows\system32` you should be able to put it anywhere

Answer (score 6):

I did it like that:

1st bat:

```
startupload.bat
ftp -i -s:upload.bat
```

2nd bat:
upload.bat :

```
open ftp.yourserver.com
username 
password 
cd public_html 
cd Ftp 
binary
put C:\Users\Desktop\something.txt
bye
```

you run it by opening `startupload.bat` (if that doesn't work, open `cmd.exe` and move `startupload.bat` in it and hit Enter. It will show you where is problem)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to upload to server is make a script file :
Code :

```
(
echo USERNAME
echo PASSWORD
echo asc
echo put C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\ftptest\thetest.txt
echo quit
)>temp.txt
ftp SERVER_DOAMIN -s:temp.txt
del temp.txt /q >nul
```

So, the USERNAME is a username, and PASSWORD is a password, SERVER_DOMAIN is a server domain (not ftp:// at the top)

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file like this:

```
@echo off

echo USERNAME> upload.txt
echo PASSWORD>> upload.txt
echo asc>>upload.txt
echo put UPLOAD_FILE_NAME FTP_PATH_TO_STORE_FILE>> upload.txt
echo quit >> upload.txt


ftp -s:upload.txt SERVER_NAME.COM

del upload.txt
```

`UPLOAD_FILE_NAME` : - you can store file to be uploaded in the same directory where the batch file exists or give file name with absoulte path.I.e I need to upload a file called `register.exe` I should use

`echo put register.exe`, If `register.exe` is exists in the batch directory or
echo put d:\myfiles\register.exe, If `register.exe` is exists in another folder(myfiles folder in d drive)

`FTP_PATH_TO_STORE_FILE`:- This is the FTP path where I need to put my file.For example /home/myftpfolder/register.exe

`del upload.txt` :- its optional because when executes batch file this `upload.txt` will stores in the directory with FTP username and password

If I've my server name is `theserver.com` then the batch file should be write like

```
@echo off
echo user123> upload.txt
echo 123TTyyy#>> upload.txt
echo asc>>upload.txt
echo put register.exe /home/myfiles/register.exe>> upload.txt
echo quit >> upload.txt
 ftp -s:upload.txt theserver.com
del upload.txt
```