# FTP via batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have searched the forum and found a few posts related to this question, but the answers I am looking for were not in the posts.

I am pulling my references from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937963/batch-file-to-upload-txt-to-ftp?rq=1).

In this batch file, the user has specified the following:

```
@echo off
echo user ahk@proflightsimulatoreview.com> ftpcmd.dat
echo ahktest>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.proflightsimulatoreview.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

My questions are as follows:

1. The put command says `%1`. If I wanted to specify a file in a different directory, could I just put the path of that directory after the put command? Assuming the bat file does not reside in the same dir as the file I want to send.
2. The put command says `%1`, and the user executes the `MYFTP.BAT c:\temp\hello.txt` from the command line. I am not executing anything from the command line but calling the bat file from another application. If I do not want to pass a parameter, can I hardcode in the path and replace the `%1`?
3. The `ftp` command is embedded in the `.bat` file as `ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.proflightsimulatoreview.com`. If I wanted to remove the step of writing to a file then calling the file, what is the FTP syntax? What is the advantage of writing to a file and calling a file that you then delete vs just putting the values straight into the FTP command?

Comment: You should ask one specific question, per question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Mark was able to answer the question(s). I appreciate the help, Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend you put your `%1` in double quotes in your script in case your filename has a space in it, i.e. in case the user does:

```
MYFTP.BAT "C:\Programs and Junk\Path with Space\file.txt"
```

Questions 1 & 2 share a common underpinning, which when you understand it, will help you see they are related. When you do:

```
PUT FILE.TXT
```

the FTP protocol takes `FILE.TXT` in the current directory, and ***because you have not specified a destination file*** it puts it in the current directory on the FTP server with the same name. So, you are going to have problems if you do this:

```
PUT C:\FREDDYFROG\FILE.txt
```

unless the FTP server has directory called "C:\FREDDYFROG" which is extremely unlikely on a Unix server! So you should consider specifying a filename on the server as follows:

```
PUT C:\FREDDYFROG\FILE.TXT SomeFile.txt
```

Further more, you can change directory on the server, with `CD` so that uploaded files "*land*" in a different directory on the server. You can also change directory locally on your machine with `LCD`. So the following command will upload local file `\FREDDYFROG\FILE.TXT` into the server's filesystem at `/incoming/somefile.txt`

```
LCD \FREDDYFROG
CD /incoming
PUT FILE.TXT somefile.txt
```

as will the following

```
PUT \FREDDYFROG\FILE.TXT /incoming/somefile.txt
```

Finally, your third question. You ***have*** to put the commands in a file with Microsft's FTP client, it doesn't read commands from standard input as far as I know.

You may prefer `curl` over Micorosft's FTP client if available and that will obviate the need to create temporary script files and do the whole lot in one go like this:

```
curl -v -u user:password -T \FREDDYFROG\FILE.TXT ftp://server/mydir/somefile.txt
```