# How do i upload to HTTP/FTP server(not mine) with Batch

Tags: http, batch-file, file-upload, cmd, upload

Is there a way to upload/write to a online file on the HTTP or ftp protocal?

> ***Echo Cats > [http://databasebyaad.000webhostapp.com/findtes.txt](http://databasebyaad.000webhostapp.com/findtes.txt_)***

Wont work

```
i wont be here if you answer BLAMESCHOOL
```

Comment: how do you do this without a batch file?

Comment: You might try `wput`. http://wput.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of Batch to FTP I've seen here before.

Otherwise the only other alternate way you can achieve this from my knowledge is a HTML form run from a HTA script on your desktop.

MyForm.hta

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
    Sub Window_onLoad
        window.resizeTo 700,700
    End Sub 
</SCRIPT>
<iframe src="https://yourwebsite.com/hta.html" title="noscript net-paste" 
width="90%" height="90%">
```

Have hta.html write content to your fintes.txt

also try read this for the method that does use Batch [Batch File To Upload .txt to FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937963/batch-file-to-upload-txt-to-ftp)