# Script batch copy file from local desktop folder to folder on server by ftp

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

how to create a batch to copy the file from local pc to server by ftp?

I created this to get the opposite, but I can't do this now.

```
open **.**.**.**
user
password
binary
get /www.mydomain.it/testTrasfFtp.txt
quit
```

some idea?

Comment: See [Batch file to upload .txt to FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7937963/850848).

Comment: @Martin Prikryl your suggestion it's ok for me. Thanks a lot